# SQL case statement in where clause fails

Tags: sql, sql-server

This works fine

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProcedure] 
    @Cond_1 AS nvarchar(50), 
    @Cond_2 AS nvarchar(50),
    @ApprovalFilter AS nvarchar(1)
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE Field_1 = @Cond_1 
      AND Field_2 = @Cond_2
END
```

This fails

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProcedure] 
    @Cond_1 AS nvarchar(50), 
    @Cond_2 AS nvarchar(50),
    @ApprovalFilter AS nvarchar(1)
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT *   
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE
        CASE
            WHEN @ApprovalFilter = 'A' 
                THEN [My Approval Column] IS NULL
            WHEN @ApprovalFilter = 'B' 
                THEN [My Approval Column] IS NOT NULL
            ELSE [My Approval Column] LIKE '%'
        END;
        AND Field_1 = @Cond_1 
        AND Field_2 = @Cond_2
END
```

Specifically this part is causing the problem

```
    CASE
        WHEN @ApprovalFilter = 'A' 
            THEN [My Approval Column] IS NULL
        WHEN @ApprovalFilter = 'B' 
            THEN [My Approval Column] IS NOT NULL
        ELSE [My Approval Column] LIKE '%'
    END;
```

Any suggestion about how to handle this?

Using Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: The result of your `CASE` expression is a boolean. E.g. `[My Approval Column] IS NULL` is either true or false. SQL Server, however, does not support a bolean data type, so it results in an error.

Comment: It's a CASE *expression*, it returns a scalar value. It is usually preferable to use `AND` `OR` in a `WHERE`. Like `(@ApprovalFilter='A' AND [My Approval Column] IS NULL) OR (@ApprovalFilter='B' AND [My Approval Column] IS NOT NULL)`

Comment: Checking the official documentation would have resolved this for you.

Comment: Looking up the documentation only helps when you know what to look for (in this case: does SQL Server support booleans?). Instead of "This fails", however, you should have told us what happens, @Sixthsense. You are probably getting an error message. Which? Never say something like "it doesn't work" without teling us what hapens exactly.

Comment: @Dale K: So what? Such a case expression is totally fine in standard SQL and works as expected in PostgreSQL ([demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c03fb2f759586653c57edb02a51b6bd9)) and MySQL [(demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c03fb2f759586653c57edb02a51b6bd9)) for instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of your `CASE` expression is a boolean. E.g. `[My Approval Column] IS NULL` is either true or false. SQL Server, however, does not support a boolean data type, so it results in an error.

As the `WHERE` clause alreeady contains a boolean expression, you don't have to use `CASE` expressions there, anyway. Just use `AND` and `OR` with the appropriate parentheses.

I suppose you want something along the lines of

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE 
(
   (@ApprovalFilter = 'A' AND [My Approval Column] IS NULL)
  OR
   (@ApprovalFilter = 'B' AND [My Approval Column] IS NOT NULL)
  OR
   @ApprovalFilter NOT IN ('A', 'B')
  OR
   @ApprovalFilter IS NULL)
)
AND Field_1 = @Cond_1 
AND Field_2 = @Cond_2
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the usage of `CASE` is not correct - it has to be on one side of an equation. However, I would suggest something like this:

```
WHERE ([My Approval Column] IS NULL AND 1 = CASE(@ApprovalFilter)
                                              WHEN 'A' THEN 1
                                              ELSE 0
                                            END)
  OR ([My Approval Column] IS NOT NULL AND 1 = CASE(@ApprovalFilter)
                                                 WHEN 'B' THEN 1
                                                 ELSE 0
                                               END)
  OR @ApprovalFilter NOT IN ('A', 'B')
```